# how to set viewpager in android activity which extend BaseActivity with drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I have a android project with `BaseActivity` which implement drawer for other activities. every thing is okey but my problem is, when I need to add a viewpager in one extended activity viewpager doesn't work and tabhost doesn't show!
I've used the same code without the `BaseActivity` and everything works, but in this case it doesn't work. I guess when I pass the `FragmentManager` of activity to the viewpager adapter something goes wrong.
can anyone help me ?

P.S: bellow is part of my code :

BaseActivity Class :

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private RecyclerView mRecycler;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private RelativeLayout FullLayout;
private FrameLayout ContentLayout;

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    FullLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);
    ContentLayout = (FrameLayout) FullLayout.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, ContentLayout, true);
    super.setContentView(FullLayout);

    //Drawer Initialization
    InitilizeDrawer();
}
}
```

MainActivity Class (Which Has ViewPager) :

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

private StaticMaterialTabs tabHost;
private ViewPager pager;
private MainTabbarAdapter pagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Init View Pager
    tabHost = (StaticMaterialTabs) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new MainTabbarAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    tabHost.setViewPager(pager);

}
}
```

BaseActivity Layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="7dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity Layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ir.MaterialTab.StaticMaterialTabs
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/Gray"
    app:mtIndicatorColor="@color/ScrollColor"
    app:mtMrlRippleColor="@color/ScrollColor"
    app:mtPaddingMiddle="false"
    app:mtSameWeightTabs="false"
    app:mtTextColorSelected="@color/White" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost" />
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Does it crash? The views just aren't visible? Have other views worked when extending BaseActivity?

Comment: @HannahMitt nothing crash, viewpager (tabhost) doesn't show, just first fragment of them become visible! yes other activity with drawer are okey.

Comment: It sounds like your tabhost may just not be set up correctly.

Comment: @HannahMitt I use it before in a separate activity and it works :-s

Comment: @Evil How did u resolved this? I am getting same issue. Please Help.

Comment: @Bhavana Sorry I can't remember the problem, but I add some working example you can try. if you have any problem please let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same problem, I found the working example as below:

BaseActivity Class:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private RecyclerView mRecycler;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private RelativeLayout FullLayout;
private FrameLayout ContentLayout;

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    FullLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);
    ContentLayout = (FrameLayout) FullLayout.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, ContentLayout, true);
    super.setContentView(FullLayout);

    //Drawer Initialization
    InitilizeDrawer();
}
```

BaseActivity Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="7dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity Class (With ViewPager):

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

private StaticMaterialTabs tabHost;
private ViewPager pager;
private MainTabbarAdapter pagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Init View Pager
    tabHost = (StaticMaterialTabs) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new MainTabbarAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    tabHost.setViewPager(pager);
}
```

MainActivity Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

<ir.MaterialTab.StaticMaterialTabs
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/Gray"
    app:mtIndicatorColor="@color/ScrollColor"
    app:mtMrlRippleColor="@color/ScrollColor"
    app:mtPaddingMiddle="false"
    app:mtSameWeightTabs="false"
    app:mtTextColorSelected="@color/White" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost" />

</LinearLayout>
```

P.S: I can't remember what was the problem (because it was for the past), so just add this tested answer for those that have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Evil. Will try this and let you now

Comment: @Bhavana your welcome, please let me now if this not work.